# domainMemory issue with Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I am new to ActionScript development and I'm trying to use the Loader to load an external SWF.

That external SWF (I'll call it SWF1) uses the Loader too to load another external SWF (I'll call it SWF2).
SWF2 uses blooddy crypto library's base64. Therefore it is using DomainMemory to improve speed (if I understood it correctly).

However, DomainMemory is causing some issues apparently and I have no idea of where it is coming from.
I'm using FlashDevelop under Windows with Flex 4.6.0 + AIR 15.0 SDK.

Here is the error thrown :

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property domainMemory not found on flash.system.ApplicationDomain and there is no default value.
>
> > at by.blooddy.crypto::Base64$/decode()
> >     at MethodInfo-6()

And here is the portion of code used to load SWF1 if it helps.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
loader.loadBytes(content, loaderContext);
```

I made some research on Google about a problem like this, but found nothing. It seems like I'm the only one who ever got that error, really weird.

Does someone know what could cause that issue ?
If you have any additional questions, just ask.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question but it solves the issue and it's the correct way to structure things - you shouldn't load swfs.  Just have one swf.  The only thing you should load is data - xml, bitmaps, jpegs, etc.  Loading swfs is a security issue which is why it's so restricted and blocked.

Comment: You're totally right, but I don't really have the choice. I can't do it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you are new to **AS3** then it's possible your main code is missing this:

```
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
```

I don't use **Flex** but I guess it all goes inside an `<mx: script>` tag..

```
<mx:Script>

    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;

    //along with your other class imports here

    //rest of AS3 code here

</mx:Script>
```

If that fails try setting it up something like this (hijacked from: **[this example](https://code.google.com/p/maashaack/wiki/ApplicationDomain)**)

```
var AD:ApplicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext( false, AD );
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes( data, context );
```

Comment: I already had that import. I don't use flex neither, I'm just using the SDK (for an unknown reason, I just followed a tutorial on Google to get started). Since your response, I tried installing Flash Builder. I just switched to Flash Builder without changing anything and all is working fine now. I still don't know what was causing that issue though. Thanks for your help anyway :).